# asmx web service and IoC

Tags: web-services, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I register components in global.asax.I resolve in try block in every web method and release in finally block. I created a wrapper for container so that it is called directly only during registration. Web methods call this wrapper to resolve and release components. This try finally adds a lot of boilerplate code. 
Am I doing right? If not how should I do it? I am using Castle Windsor.

```
[WebMethod]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ISomeComponent c = null
    try
    {
        c = myContainer.ResolveSomeComponent();
        c.Method();
    }
    finally
    {
        myContainer.Release(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). It describes how to write highly maintainable web services.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help me. First it's not asmx web service. Second I don't see where it releases resolved components.

Comment: The referred article describes a way of designing your system and it can be used with WCF, Web API and asmx (although asmx could be a little harder). When you design the system like this the problem of releasing goes away completely, since you will only have to 'maintain' one single web service method and not maintain hundreds of methods with hundreds of release calls.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But I'm working with legacy code. And it's impossible to change it the way you propose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. As it turns out I can configure my components as Per Web Request and then I don't have to release them because they will be automatically released at the end of request.

You can find details in this article: http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor.aspx